# If $0$ $\leq$ $f(t)$ $\leq$ $1$, and $0$ $\leq$ $\frac{\partial f(t)}{\partial t}$ $\leq$ $\frac 12$. Does $f(t)$ have any fixed points?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Let $f(t)$ be a differentiable function for $t$ $\in$ $[0,1]$ satisfying the above,

Does $f(t)$ have any fixed points?

I can easily prove there always exists fixed points without the second condition using $MVT$,

does $0$ $\leq$ $\frac{\partial f(t)}{\partial t}$ $\leq$ $\frac 12$ change anything?

I am very curious to know the answer of this problem, and note fixed points are  when; $f(x)=x$

Comment: Are you missing a number? You have $f(t) \le$ with nothing else there.

Comment: @ChristopherA. Wong yes thank-you

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong I have again edited my question for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint. Let g(t)=f(t)-t.
Now use the intermediate value theorem to show that there are fixed points.
For bonus, show that the fixed point is unique!
Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You definitely have fixed points, by an Intermediate Value theorem argument: let $g(t):= f(t)-t$.  Then $g(0) \ge 0$ and $g(1)< 0$ so using only continuity one necessarily obtains a fixed point, which solves $g(t^*)=0$.

But, $f'(t) \ge 0$ implies that your function is always increasing, and $f' \le \frac{1}{2}$ implies that $g'(t) < 0$ for all $t$, in particular at $t^*$.

So what if, for sake of contradiction, $g$ had two zeroes: $t^*$ and $t^{**}$?  Without loss $t^* < t^{**}$, hence $g(t^{**})<g(t^*)$, but by hypothesis $g(t^*) = g(t^{**})$! Thus your fixed point is unique.

Comment: Why is g'(t) strictly less than 0 ?

Comment: Well, $g(t) = f(t) - t$.  So $\frac{dg(t)}{dt}$ is just $f'(t) - 1$.  Now we know $f'(t)$ lives in $[0,0.5]$ so no matter what, $g'(t) < 1$!

Comment: Yes of course thankyou